# Obtener datos con $_GET['id'] en php y sql me está volviendo loco

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo una base de datos SQL de la que obtengo datos y hago la paginación con este código php:

### Código

```
<?php
    $servename = "localhost";
    $database = "NombreDB";
    $username = "UserBD";
    $password = "ContraseñaDB";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servename, $username, $password, $database);
    mysqli_query($conn, "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");

    if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed" . mysqli_connect_eror());
    }

// Aquí es donde ajustas los registros
$elementosPorPagina = 10; 
$paginaActual = isset($_GET['pagina']) ? $_GET['pagina'] : 25;
$inicio = ($paginaActual - 1) * $elementosPorPagina;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM revistas ORDER BY fecha ASC, id ASC LIMIT $inicio, $elementosPorPagina";
$resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Database error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
?>


<!-- y esta seria la sección de paginación -->
<div class="pagination">
<?php
$sqlTotal = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM revistas";

$resultTotal = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlTotal);
$filaTotal = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultTotal);
$totalElementos = $filaTotal['total'];
$totalPaginas = ceil($totalElementos / $elementosPorPagina);
    if ($paginaActual > 1) {
        echo "<a href='?pagina=" . ($paginaActual - 1) . "'>&laquo; Anterior</a> ";
    }
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalPaginas; $i++) {
        $claseActiva = ($i == $paginaActual) ? 'active' : '';
        echo "<a class='$claseActiva' href='?pagina=$i'>$i</a> ";
    }
    if ($paginaActual < $totalPaginas) {
        echo "<a href='?pagina=" . ($paginaActual + 1) . "'>Siguiente &raquo;</a> ";    
    }
?>
</div>


<!-- en esta sección muestra el resultado -->
<?php while ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset)) { ?>
<div class="inner">
    <div class="item">
    <a href="revista.php?id=<?php echo $record['id'];?>" title="<?php echo '' . $record['titulo'] ?>">
        <img class="img-preview"><?php echo '' . $record['portada'] ?>
    </a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php mysqli_close($conn); ?>
```

Bien todo este código funciona perfectamente hace la paginación y muestra los resultados de la base de datos, esto es como si fuera la portada de una web y le he añadido la opción de **leer más** con el siguiente código:

```
    <a href="revista.php?id=<?php echo $record['id'];?>" title="<?php echo '' . $record['titulo'] ?>">
```

para que valla al enlace y muestre los resultados de los detalles o sea la continuación de "leer mas".

Esto también lo hace correctamente ya que con `<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>` Me devuelve el `id` correcto de cada entrada:

### codigo de revistas.php

```
 <?php
    $servename = "localhost";
    $database = "NombreDB";
    $username = "UserBD";
    $password = "ContraseñaDB";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servename, $username, $password, $database);
mysqli_query($conn, "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed" . mysqli_connect_eror());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM revistas WHERE id='.$_GET[id]'";
$resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Database error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
?>

<!-- en esta seccion muestra el resultado -->
<div id="below-header" class="content">
    <h2><?php echo $_GET['id'];?></h2>  <!-- funciona devuelve el id correcto -->
</div>

<div id="below-title" class="content">
    <h2><?php echo $_GET['titulo'];?></h2>  <!-- esto no funciona devuelve error -->
</div>
```

El problema lo tengo a la hora de obtener otros datos que no sean el `id` de la tabla revistas
En la base de datos en la tabla de revistas tengo varias columnas así como *titulo, año, fecha,* etc... y no se como obtener esos datos. Necesito obtener los datos en `revistas.php`  no se si me explico.

Gracias y Saludos

Comment: Hola. Esos datos estarían en `$resultset` y los puedes obtener mediante `mysqli_fetch_assoc` o de otro modo. Tu error es que estás buscando esos datos adicionales en la supergloblal `$_GET`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esos datos estarían en `$resultset` y los puedes obtener mediante `mysqli_fetch_assoc` o de otro modo. Tu error es que estás buscando esos datos adicionales en la supergloblal `$_GET`.

Así debería funcionar:

#### `revistas.php`

```
<?php
    $servename = "localhost";
    $database = "id21683535";
    $username = "id21683535";
    $password = "MiGata";
    
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servename, $username, $password, $database);
    mysqli_query($conn, "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed" . mysqli_connect_eror());
    }
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM revistas WHERE id='.$_GET[id]'";
    $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Database error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
    # Metemos los datos en la variable $fila
    $fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset);  
?>
    
    <!-- en esta seccion muestra el resultado -->
    <div id="below-header" class="content">
        <h2><?php echo $_GET['id'];?></h2>  <!-- funciona devuelve el id correcto -->
    </div>
    
    <div id="below-title" class="content">
        <h2><?php echo $fila['titulo'];?></h2>  <!-- debería funcionar -->
    </div>
```

Asumo que la columna se llama `titulo`. En `$fila` vas a tener un array asociativo con los nombres de columna y sus valores respectivos. Para otra(s) columna(s), haces los mismo: `$fila['elNombreDeLaColumna']`.

Si esperas más de una fila, debes mover la llamada a `mysqli_fetch_assoc` dentro de un `while`, como muestran los ejemplos de esa función en el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

Por último, advertir que tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Deberías implementar consultas preparadas para evitar ese gravísimo riesgo.

Comment: @Jflabur me alegro de que te haya funcionado. En cuanto a la seguridad, deberías sanear con `filter_input` aquellos datos que vienen de fuera y que piensas mostrar en el contexto del servidor con `echo`,  `print` u otros. Pero para la base de datos, debes usar las herramientas propias de las cuales la mejor son las consultas preparadas. Ese código con `filter_input` NO previene la inyección SQL. **Filtrar entradas y prevenir inyección SQL no son la misma cosa**.

Comment: Gracias buscare información y solucionare la vulneravilidad

Comment: @Jflabur Sí. [Aquí mismo hay varias preguntas/respuestas sobre el tema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=mysqli%2bconsultas%20preparadas&searchOn=3). Y, cualquier duda al implementarlo puedes abrir una nueva pregunta si te quedas bloqueado.

Comment: Muchas gracias ahora paso por esa sección y le hecho un vistazo..

Answer (score 0):

Gracias ya lo he probado y funciona perfectamente.
Acerca del código altamente vulnerable, he implementado esta funcion:

```
$filteredId = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
// te devuelve el entero si pasa el filtro,
// o false si no lo pasó, entonces puedes
// rechazar la entrada o abortar
if(is_null($filteredId) || $filteredId === FALSE) {
   exit('Dato no validado');
}
// ahora sí, usamos el dato filtrado
$sql = "SELECT * FROM peliculas WHERE id='$filteredId'";
```

será la mejora suficiente??

Comment: No. Eso no es suficiente. Revisa mi comentario en la respuesta. Por otra parte, no uses el área de respuestas para cuestiones aclaratorias. Esta área debe usarse sólo para respuestas a la pregunta original.